# super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) crashes in first run

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-lifecycle, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Exception that caught by Firebase Crash Reporting:

> **Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.talmir.mickinet/com.talmir.mickinet.activities.HomeActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>   0x7f080058** android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2249)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2299) android.app.ActivityThread.access$700
>   (ActivityThread.java:154) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   ...
>
> **Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>   0x7f080058 android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:1883)**
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.c (SourceFile:332)
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.a (SourceFile:197)
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable
>   ...

**HomeActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); // line 238
FirebaseCrash.log("HomeActivity");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    if (!canAccessCamera() || !canAccessExternalStorage() || !canAccessContacts())
        requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMISSIONS, INITIAL_REQUEST);

copyRawFile(R.raw.file_receive);
// other codes...
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.talmir.mickinet.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:background="@color/snow">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_list"
            class="com.talmir.mickinet.fragments.DeviceListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/phone_list_height">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_detail"
            class="com.talmir.mickinet.fragments.DeviceDetailFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            // my config
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.talmir.mickinet"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What I tested:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38296988/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31396837), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41956170), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19450302) one(s). The question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38092967) looks like more close to my problem than others.

Moreover, the same application installed in API 23 and API 17 (both are physical devices), but error occurs only in API 17 (when it launches).

## Main question:

Why this exception happens and how can I solve it?

Comment: i think there is an error in your activity_home.xml, paste the xml file

Comment: if the error related with layout file, it should be mention the line 239 not 238. read the question carefully please. on the other hand, the problem should also occurs both smartphones, if it would be related with content in the layout file.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski does it crash on another device with API level 17 as well?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski Resources$NotFoundException most probably chances occur in xml file

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski maybe you specified a different layout XML for the api level 17 device?

Comment: @WilliMentzel I edited the question. ;) :)

Comment: @Vishal if it is, it should be in line number 239.

Comment: @WilliMentzel no, I did not do it. Triple checked:)

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski remove the build.gradle from the question (it does not matter) and show the layout xml pls.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski Do you use android studio canary 6?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski which version of android studio do you use?

Comment: @WilliMentzel I am not able to make any changes in the question (due to I lost electricity at home).

Comment: @Mohad12211 yes it is Android Studio 3.0 canary 6 version

Comment: @WilliMentzel check the layout file. I added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception happens to me when I update the Android Studio from Canary 5 to canary 6

I return to Android Studio 2.3.2 and changed the class path back to Gradle 2.3.2 and the problem was solved.

Update: I tried with 3 of my applications and I get the same error, but solved it like described.

Comment: does it happen with all of your applications?

Comment: i didnt check that but i tried all the solutions and no one works .. also your exception is exactly same of me .. try to do this

Comment: @Mohad12211 I don't think this Exception has anything to do with Android Studio. :(

Comment: Just try, and make sure that you change the class path in the dependencies to : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' // change 2.3.2 to the version you use.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski I dont think you tried my answer, just try. Iam sure 90% that this is the problem

Comment: @WilliMentzel i thought like you, but i tried all the solutions and none of them work, i tried this and it works

Comment: @Mohad12211 no actually I tested it. I did not change my android studio version but downgraded gradle version from `3.0.0-alpha6` to `2.3.3` and now everything working **perfectly!** Thanks a lot. You saved my time! :)

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski never use an alpha version in production ;)

Comment: @WilliMentzel I got it now :) This will not happen second time again :D
Thanks to you too))

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue today. After some research, I found this:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Add this line into your "gradle.properties" file.

Reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057409/8301396).

I think it's caused by a bug in latest version (3.0 Canary 6) of Android Studio.

> Improved incremental resource processing with AAPT2. To enable AAPT2, add the following to your gradle.properties file: android.enableAapt2=true

The text above is from [android studio preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin.html) link.